# cascading for the impatient part 1 gradle guild fails

Tags: hadoop, gradle, cascading

I've just gotten Gradle 1.4 and Hadoop 2.7.0. on my Ubuntu 14.04 VM.

I'm in the part1 directory for the Cascading for the Impatient tuturial repo.

When I run 'gradle clean jar', I get the following:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/Impatient/build.gradle' line: 29

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'impatient'.
> Could not find method jcenter() for arguments [] on repository container.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.502 secs
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction as to how to approach resolving this issue?

Also, the [tutorial](http://docs.cascading.org/impatient/) suggested using an IDE, and I installed Intellij, which was recommended. When I run 'gradle ideaModule', I get the same build failure message as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Gradle 1.4 and the tutorial claims to have been tested with Gradle 1.12, so you could simply try to upgrade Gradle to 1.12 if possible.

jcenter() was added in Gradle 1.7 according to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27477763/4563229

Using the wrapper as described in the other answer should also work.

Comment: I upgraded to gradle 1.12 and that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution from this question - [Could not find method jcenter() for arguments [] on repository container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470443/could-not-find-method-jcenter-for-arguments-on-repository-container)

"I ran into the same error. The following method (as described here) worked for me.

Add a task

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '2.0'
}
```

and run it once. Afterwards, start using `gradlew` instead of `gradle`"