# gradle - Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

 allprojects {
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

Comment: Find the file named: gradle-wrapper.properties, and change the distributionUrl value to:  "https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip"

Comment: You can refer this link for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52039526/5689801

Comment: A poorly written answer in the link and someone jumped rope to mark this as duplicate.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52566323/6401241

Comment: upgrade gradle.wrapper.properties  i am sure you will get a correct result.