# Could not find method jcenter() for arguments [] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to learn android development, but I can't setup my Android Studio, because there is always this error:
`Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method jcenter() for arguments [] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.`

Can you tell me please, how to solve this?

EDIT: I forgot to add `build.gradle` file.

Here it is:

```
    repositories { google() jcenter() mavenCentral() maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } } dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories { google() jcenter() mavenCentral() maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also share your project gradle files

Comment: @GurgenArustamyan I already changed my question

Comment: Maybe this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470443/could-not-find-method-jcenter-for-arguments-on-repository-container